# Add and remove div tag with table caption

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make my code run but the insertAfter inserts the div after the first div tag not the last.
I want to dynamically apend it after the last one.
 Also if the user clicks remove button then div in which the remove button is clicked should be eliminated. 
My caption is also not working well. There are some minor adjustment required.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var uniqueId = 1;
    $("#addRequest").click(function() {
        var RequestDiv = "#div_" + $('#combo_3 option:selected').val() + "_1";
        var RequestTableCap = "tbl_" + $('#combo_3 option:selected').val();
        if ($(RequestDiv).is(":visible")) {
            var template = $(RequestDiv).clone();
            uniqueId++;

            template.find('input,select,textarea,table').each(function() {
                var newId = this.id.substring(0, this.id.length - 1) + uniqueId;
                $(this).prev().attr('for', newId); // update label for
                this.name = this.id = newId; // update id and name (assume the same)    
            })

            .end()
            .attr('id', 'div_data_1_1_1_1_' + uniqueId)
            .appendTo('#idRequestDetails');

            var TableCaption = 'Request #:  ' + uniqueId + '  ' + $('#combo_2 option:selected').text() + '    ' + $('#combo_1                        option:selected').text() + ' (' + $('#combo_3 option:selected').text() + ')';
            var tbcaption = document.getElementById('RequestTableCap').createCaption()
            tbcaption.innerHTML = TableCaption

        }

        if ($(this).attr("enabled", true)) {
            if ($("#div_data_1_1_1_1_1").is(":hidden")) {
                $(RequestDiv).slideDown("fast"); //Slide Down Effect
                var RequestTableCap = "tbl_" + $('#combo_3 option:selected').val();
                var TableCaption = 'Request #:  ' + uniqueId + '  ' + $('#combo_2 option:selected').text() + '    ' + $('#combo_1 option:selected').text() + ' (' + $('#combo_3 option:selected').text() + ')';
                var tbcaption = document.getElementById(RequestTableCap).createCaption()
                tbcaption.innerHTML = TableCaption;

            }
        }
        else {

            $(RequestDiv).slideUp("fast"); //Slide Up Effect
        }

    });
    $('.removeReq').click(function() {
        $(this).closest.attr('div').remove();

    });
});
```

Comment: 1) Why are you cloning a clone? (`template`). 2) If you want to insert after the last of something, can't you use `appendTo`?

Comment: Hi Utanos, appendTo inserts within the same div tag and I want to insert as a new div tag. I can see the clone issue. Not very expert. can you fix it ?

Comment: 1. I want to make .insertAfter dynamic not static but dont know how ? hopefully once that done then the problem of inserting it after the end of div tag (based on uniqueId ) would also be solved. Secondly .remove ??? and caption (my caption is js based) could not find any way in doing it in jQ. Any help please....

Comment: What I meant was, if your DIVs are in a common container, you can just use `appendTo`, i.e. `template.appendTo('#the_container')`

Comment: Thanks, I think the flow of DIVs is ok now, but Caption is still not working and have to get .remove working too.